# C # FFMPEG I GET ERRORS IN MPEG2 AND MPEG4 FORMAT?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ffmpeg, mpeg-4, mpeg-2

I am making a converter using the ffmepg library via c # form. I can convert all my videos to whatever format I want. But I get the following error in mpeg2, mpeg, mpeg4 formats. My code is;

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "mpeg2")
            {
                var convert = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
                convert.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, MusicPath, "mpeg2");
                MessageBox.Show("convert is okey");
            }
```

**is my fault;
**NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegException: 'C:\Users\zbaran\Videos\New folder\ converted Alan Walker, Sabrina Carpenter & Farruko  - On My Way.webm.mpeg2: Invalid argument (exit code: 1)'

what should I do? Please Help! But the other format is working. I havent any error.

Comment: Does the graphic card on your machine support mpeg2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the documentation: 
https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.VideoConverter/ 
and it seems like they have a Format class. The string they use for mpeg is just "mpeg". So, this should work:

```
convert.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, MusicPath, "mpeg");
```

or this

```
convert.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, MusicPath, Format.mpeg);
```

mpeg4 would be

```
convert.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, MusicPath, "mp4");
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much! mpeg mpg2 and mpeg4 because I think there are separate formats I wrote as I mentioned above. Thanks a lot mpeg4 mp4 as we should think?

Comment: Great! I'm not really that familiar with these formats and differences, but in the Format class they provide, there are only Format.mpeg and Format.mp4

Comment: Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Does it support 4k resolution?
I also have the code but I get the error again; 'var ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
                    ffmpeg.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, null, MusicPath, null, new ConvertSettings()
                    {
                        CustomOutputArgs = "-s 4k"
                    }); '

Comment: or;var ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
                    ffmpeg.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, null, MusicPath, null, new ConvertSettings()
                    {
                        CustomOutputArgs = "-s uhd2160"
                    });   like this